# Class variable assigned by expression

Tags: python, class, static-members

I have a *class variable* - a list - which values generated dynamically by comprehension, for example:

```
class A:
    Field = [2**x for x in range(8)]
    . . .
```

My question: is this value calculated once the class `A` was imported or every time I call the `A.Field`? How Python treats such declarations, is there some limitation or hidden hurdles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression is evaluated once, when the `class` statement is being executed (in Python, things like `class` and `def` [are executable statements](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/how-everything-became-executable.html)).

When you do this, all instance of `A` or subclasses will share the same `Field`.

> ...is this value calculated once the class A was imported...

Note that there is no "imported" here. If you place the `class` statement inside a module, and import that module more than once, the statement will still only get executed once.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example showing that it is evaluated only once:

```
>>> l=range(2)
>>> l
[0, 1]
>>> class A:
...   Field = l.pop()
...
>>> A.Field
1
>>> A.Field
1
>>> l
[0]
```

the `.pop()` is executed only once.